# get pointer for existing device class (struct class) in Linux kernel module

Tags: linux, driver, device

get pointer for existing device class (`struct class`) in Linux kernel module

Hi all!

I am trying to register a device in an existing device class, but I am having trouble getting the pointer to an existing class. Kernel version is Linux 3.3.6.
I can create a class in a module, get the pointer to it and then use it to register the device with:

```
*cl = class_create(THIS_MODULE, className);
dev_ret = device_create(*cl, NULL, *dev, NULL, driverName);
```

However I need to register another device in the same class with another module, but I couldn't find a way to get the pointer to an existing class. And I can not create the class again in the other module, because since class already exists `class_create` returns NULL and not the pointer to the class required by `device_create`.
I found in:

http://lwn.net/Articles/102500/

A function that returns a pointer to a class by its name:

```
struct class * class_find(char * name)
```

However when I try to compile the function compiler says it does not exist.
I thought this function was exported by the kernel (my module have license GPL) but it appears it is not.
Maybe I need to include some header?

I tried to rewrite this function since, its code is list in the above link. But when I try to iterate over `class_subsys` with:

```
list_for_each_entry(this_class, &class_subsys.kset.list, subsys.kset.kobj.entry)
```

now symbol `class_subsys` is not found. Again I thought it is exported to the kernel.

I am not sure what is missing. Some header?
Am I doing it the wrong way?
There is another function to do it?

I suppose if I could traverse `sysfs` from start I could get a pointer to  an existing class. 
But I also did not find how to start traversing `sysfs`.
All functions I have seen requires a pointer to `kobject` or `kset` to start traversing. But I have no pointer even to the root of `sysfs` or kernel objects, so I can not start traversing the tree to get a class pointer.

Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

Comment: The link you referenced describes a patch which never made it into the Linux kernel -- which is why you aren't able to call `class_find`. Here's the relevant LKML thread: https://lkml.org/lkml/2004/9/16/83.

Comment: hi, have you sovled this problem? I stuck in this problem too.

Answer (score 0):

I think input core is done this way, here is the snippet

Take a look at: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/input/input.c#L1720

Best regards!